# Network: How redirect a hostname to a ip?

Tags: routes, network-programming, package, router

i have this hostname ( valterhenrique.sytes.net ) , i created it in [No IP](http://www.no-ip.com).
But i need to redirect this hostname to my machine which ip is 192.168.1.149 .

How can i do this ?

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

192.168.1.149 is a [private IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). It will not be routed outside of your network.

Have a look in your router configuration interface. Usually there is a setting for updating DynamicDNS like No-IP automatically to your current WAN IP and a setting to forward a port from your local machine (192.168.1.149) to the outside world.

Comment: i already have a client application that keeps my outside ip updated with no-ip, but i don't get it how i gonna do the forward. cause its requires the port and the ip of my LAN.

Comment: You are behind a router. You need to configure the router to accept connections on for example port 80 of your WAN and redirect them to for example port 8080 on your local machine and vice versa.

Comment: now i found it the DynamicDNS as you said in my router options.

Comment: the solutions to my problem was :
i set up a DMZ to the machine that is running what i want to access from outside.
then i set up the DDNS in my router to access my ip from the hostname.
that's all folks =)